# Repeat loop every 'x' ms

Tags: c++, windows, loops, syntax, repeat

I'm trying to write a loop that runs once every x milliseconds, is there a way to do something like this effectively in c++?

Hope someone could help me with an example how I would go about writing a loop like this

Comment: Needs dedicated hardware and/or OS support and/or a driver and/or something.  Your requirement is way underspecified - we don't know if you can use a sleep() loop or need a hydrogen fountain clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One and the simplest approach would be using **windows.h** library's **Sleep()** function.

```
#include "windows.h" 
...
while(1) 
{
for(...) {} // your loop
Sleep(miliseconds);
if(something) { break; } // to prevent infinite looping.
}
...
```

A better solution would be using **std::this_thread::sleep_for()** from < thread > header.
[more documentation and examples here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Comment: This doesn't guarantee execution every n ms, it assumes no other code is ever run (the code that is being run takes time...) And the system provided sleep functions are not accurate.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Agree. As i said using Sleep() function, would get the job done, however with some losses. The second solution i proposed is better and more accurate.

Comment: Thanks, I remember Java and C# having a function that measures the time taken from a specific line to another and saves the time in a variable. Is there something similar for C++?

Comment: @ColdZer0 check the link i've provided on std::this_thread::sleep_for(), the example is exactly what you're asking right now.